# Transfer MCPE World from iPad to iPhone on creative during LAN party

Tags: ios, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was able to be on the world on both devices, but when I went into the pause menu on the iPhone that I wanted to "quit and copy world" to, the pause menu only had the typical "back to game", "options", and "quit to title" in the pause menu, not a "quit and copy world".

Thanks for any help!